# pack/unpack - litle endian - 64bit - question

Tags: perl, pack, unpack

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

my $var = 1 << 31;
say unpack( "B*", pack( "N", $var )  );

# 10000000000000000000000000000000
```

How can I get with pack/unpack from

```
my $var = 1 << 63;
```

an output like this?

```
# 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
say unpack("B*", pack( "Q>", $var ));
```

The `>` forces big-endian byte-order on the `Q` (unsigned 64-bit "quad") type.

Comment: Note: 1) Quads are only available on 64-bit versions of perl. 2) Byte order modifiers require Perl 5.10 or newer.