# How do I generate an SDBM file (.dir and .pag) on a little endian that will work on a big endian using Perl?

Tags: perl, endianness

Question updated 20131001:

I've been tasked with looking into updating a Perl process that uses SDBM_File to generate an SDBM file (.dir and .pag) containing Apache redirects. The target server is big endian, and the source server is little endian. The target server cannot be updated in any way, so I'm trying to figure out how to convert these files on the source server before sending them over.

Dealing with 'endianness' is new to me, but I've figured out how to unpack/pack various types of data, relying heavily on this tutorial:  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html

My primary approach, after some digging around, involves figuring out how to convert the resulting binary file, such as the .pag file, into a format that will work on the target server. After some tinkering, I've realized that I shouldn't mess with trying to convert for the target if I can't even make a copy of the original binary file on the source machine. In the code below, I'm simply trying to unpack and pack data from one binary file into another binary file. If I can do that, I would think it would be a cinch to export it using another template. Thanks for any help - I'm testing the following on a 64bit iOS machine.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use Fcntl;   # For O_RDWR, O_CREAT, etc.
    use SDBM_File;
    use Config;
use Data::Dumper;

#notes: to see the octal dump with the hex option from command line od -x packtest.pag

# byte info
print "Byteorder: $Config{ byteorder }\n";

print unpack("h*", pack("s2", 1, 2)), "\n";
    # '10002000' on e.g. Intel x86 or Alpha 21064 in little-endian mode
    # '00100020' on e.g. Motorola 68040
print "00100020 is big-endian\n";

tie(%h, 'SDBM_File', 'packtest', O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666)
  or die "Couldn't tie SDBM file 'filename': $!; aborting";

# Add some data to the hash - will be used for Apache redirects
$h{'/from.html'} = '/to.html';

print "Before conversion: \n";
print Dumper(\%h);

#do I need to make sure it's packed in a certain way?
#%h = pack "q", %h;

untie %h;

#new file
my $data_file="packtest.pag";
open(IN, '<:raw', $data_file);
my $before = <IN>;
close(IN);

#my $after = $before;
my $tmp_after = unpack "Q", $before;
my $after = pack "Q", $tmp_after;
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672213/pack-unpack-litle-endian-64bit-question

print "After: \n";
print Dumper(\$after);

my $new_file="packtest2.pag";
open(OUT,'>:raw',$new_file) || die "error $!\n";
print OUT $after;
close(OUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dump source to ASCII -> copy to target -> build new sdbm file from ASCII.